# randomization in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog

I am trying to randomize an address which should be not fall in a previously allocated segment
suppose if I was allocated  address 0, 10 ,40 , and the block length is 5,
when I randomized the address , it should not fall in the range of (0-4) ,( 10-14) , (40-44).
how can I constraint this in system verilog.
I tried a method but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
constraint con {

foreach(keys[i]){

    !(address inside {[keys[i]:keys[i]+BLOCK_SIZE]});    
}

}
```

keys is array of address that were already alloted , generated address should not fall in the above ranges.
thanks
shiva

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax seems correct to me.  What issue do you see with it?

I tried the above and it works for me. See below code.

```
class t_constraints;  

  randc bit [2:0] addr; //using randc just to make all values appear.  

  int keys [2] = {0,4};  // Implies addr {0:1 and 4:5 should not assigned}  
  int BLOCK_SIZE = 1;  

  constraint con { foreach(keys[i])  
    {!(addr inside {[keys[i]:keys[i]+BLOCK_SIZE]});}  
  }  

endclass: t_constraints  

module tb_con;  
  t_constraints t_con;  

 initial begin  
   t_con = new();  
   repeat(8) begin  
     t_con.randomize();  
     $display("addr = %h",t_con.addr);  
   end  
   $finish;  
 end  
endmodule: tb_con
```

Below is the log, It seems perfect.

```
addr = 3  
addr = 6  
addr = 7  
addr = 2  
addr = 2  
addr = 3  
addr = 7  
addr = 6 
$finish called from file "t_constraints.sv", line 26.
```

Sorry for not formatting properly. I am not able to answer after formatting. It gives me error saying code is not formatted properly.

EDIT:
If you want to consider the addr generated each time for the next randomization, use inline constraints in tb.
See below code

```
module tb_con;
 t_constraints t_con;
 int t_keys [$];
 int T_BLOCK_SIZE;

 initial begin
   t_con = new();
   repeat(3) begin // constraint solver cannot solve since after 3rd iteration there won't be any legal values.
     t_keys = t_con.keys;
     T_BLOCK_SIZE = t_con.BLOCK_SIZE;
     t_con.randomize() with{
       foreach(t_keys[i])
         { !(addr inside {[t_keys[i]:t_keys[i]+T_BLOCK_SIZE]});} 
     };
     $display("addr = %h",t_con.addr);
     t_con.keys.push_back(t_con.addr);
   end
   $finish;
 end
endmodule: tb_con
```

NOTE: You must be careful not to iterate more than the possible values (here 3) else your simulation will exit with constraint inconsistency error.

Comment: class t_constraints;  

  randc bit [5:0] addr; //using randc just to make all values appear.  

  int keys [$] ;  // Implies addr {0:1 and 4:5 should not assigned}  
  int BLOCK_SIZE = 4;  

  constraint con { foreach(keys[i])  
    {!(addr inside {[keys[i]:keys[i]+BLOCK_SIZE]});}  
  }  

endclass: t_constraints  

module tb_con;  
  t_constraints t_con;  

 initial begin  
   t_con = new();  
   repeat(8) begin  
     t_con.randomize();  
     $display("addr = %h",t_con.addr);
  t_con.keys.push_back(t_con.addr);
   end  
   $finish;  
 end  
endmodule: tb_con

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. Please show a complete testcase and the incorrect results you are getting.

```
class a;

   rand bit [5:0] address;
   bit [5:0] keys[] = {0,10,40};
   int       BLOCK_SIZE = 5;
   constraint con {

           foreach(keys[i]) {
      !(address inside {[keys[i]:keys[i]+BLOCK_SIZE-1]}) ; }    
           }

endclass

module top;
   a a_h;
   initial begin
      a_h = new;
      repeat (200) begin
     if (!a_h.randomize())
       $error("randomize failed"); 
     $display(a_h.address);
     assert (!(a_h.address inside {[0:4],[10:14],[40:44]}));
      end
   end
endmodule // top
```